# Android share comment on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am having social networking application made by me, in which you can post comments, i want to facilitate user to one click share posted commented on user's Facebook as well.

I tried [fbconnect-android](http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/) is there any other way sharing comments on FB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have the official [FB SDK for android](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/).

> ```
> A library to integrate Facebook into your Android mobile application.
> ```